# How to set a flag in SQL, when there is a change in value

Tags: sql-server

I have column which tells fee rates.

When there is change in value in that column, I need to set a flag for that corresponding row.

How can i check whether there is change in value from previous row and current row and flag it accordingly. There are l0's of thousands of records.

[image]

Please find below, when rate changes, then that row I have to flag.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the forum! Sounds like you want a trigger to check if the previous record has a different rate to the record being inserted. You can also do this on the fly using window functions. BTW, the **"lakh"** is not commonly used as a numerical unit outside of South Asia - better to use 10s of thousands of records... Please provide your table structure as DDL and some sample data - a few records will do - best thing is to use dbfiddle.uk. Finally, when asking a question, please always include your server version since the answer may depend on that factor.

Comment: *How can i check whether there is change in value from previous row and current row* Compare value and LAG(value).

Comment: What is the name of the field to determine which row is the previous row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on yore example I assume that by "Set a flag" you want to set a value in another column in your report.
You didn't include a column which defines order of the rows, which is required for such query, I will use "id" column.
To get such flag you can use LAG function, which will return value in the previous row and compare it to current value:

```
SELECT id, rate,
CASE WHEN rate = LAG (rate) OVER (ORDER BY id) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Flag
FROM ...
ORDER BY id
```

Comment: Pitor  -- Thanks...able to set flag using LAG function, But (for first row 0 is compared with NULL) and flag is set to 1 for that as well. How can i ignore that ?

Comment: rate of first record is compared with NULL , as its not matching  flag is set to 1. How can i exclude that offset or first recod?

Comment: you can use LAG default value: LAG (scalar_expression [,offset] [,default]) , i.e. `LAG(rate, 1, rate)`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to *do* based on that flag.

- If you only care that the row has "changed" at some point, then a flag *might* be enough.
- If you care *when* the change happened, then a [nullable] timestamp might be more useful.
- If you care if the change happens *more than once*, then you need a whole new table to record *all* of those changes, possibly even with "before" [and "after"] values.

In any case, the answer is the same - a Trigger.

Comment: Not totally accurate IMHO. For the latter, a temporal table would give the same benefits without the overhead of maintaining the trigger.

Comment: @George.Palacios - I don't think a trigger is going to be significantly slower than a temporal table if well written (unless by maintain you mean coding & debugging which would be extra work on the human side). But a temporal table also gives the advantage of the syntactic sugar that makes querying the resulting data for specific points/ranges in time which can be quite valuable.

Answer (score 0):

I think simply you can write after update Trigger on your table and update the flag for the row which value updated. Let assume you have below RATES sample table and we can update the flag using below trigger.

[image]

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[UPDATE_FLAG]
ON [dbo].RATES
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

```
   DECLARE @ID  INT
   SELECT @ID = INSERTED.ID       
   FROM inserted
```

IF(@ID>0)
BEGIN

UPDATE RATES SET FALG=1 WHERE ID=@ID
END
END